# Escape angularJS terms in html while rendering it

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, templates, flask

I am using angularJS with flask at the backend.my template has angular terms like(I know they are not called terms but i cant explain it in better way)

```
       {{Person.name}} {{Person.number}}
```

I want to render this template in my flask views.

I tried to use render_template("templatename.html").
But it shows me Person not defined error.(Obviously sice i dint pass any parameters and it is not considering them to related to angular)

So i have found a workaround and used this

```
return make_response(open("templatename.html",'r').read())
```

And this works!

But now i have to pass parameters to the template and i cant do it with this workaround!
Can anyone please suggest me some other way to escape angular related terms in html and render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use different tags in Angular so that they don't conflict with those for Flask:

```
app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

and then in template:

```
<% Person.name %> <% Person.number %>
```

Check [$interpolateProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider) for details.

Comment: And then should i surround the angular terms within these tags.
As in

<%  {{Person.name}} {{Person.number}} %>

Comment: No, you use `<%` or whatever you prefer instead of `{{`: `<% Person.name %> <% Person.number %>`.